# Backslash error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Tags: python

I want to use a backslash in Python, but I always get an error. This is my code

```py
fileName = "file"
linkName = "rep\" + file_name
print(linkName)
```

The error:
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Try using '\\'. It escapes a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simple. Just had the same
Use this:

```py
fileName = "file"
linkName = "rep" + chr(92) + file_name
print(linkName)
```

chr(92) stands for \

Comment: It works in every projects for me

Comment: Yes, it *works*, but there are other solutions that don't require the reader to consult an ASCII chart to make sense of the code...

Comment: Not my downvote but just because it works doesn’t make it good code: it’s unnecessarily convoluted. The correct (= widely accepted as standard, more readable, more efficient …) solution is to escape the backslash. There’s no reason whatsoever to use `chr` here.

Comment: Yeah,  in my case it works using "\\"  instead of "\" and it's more readable.